# Dynamic variable doesnt work

Tags: c++, class, c++11, dynamic, constructor

in this code why does the first("invNummer") is always 0, when I initializate it dynamically? When I do it as a static(two) it works.

```
class Computer {
private:
    int invNummer;
    char* osName;
    int state; // 0 – aus, 1 - an
public:
    Computer(int INV, char* OS, int st);

    void info() {
        cout << invNummer << " " << osName << " " << state << endl;
    }
};

Computer::Computer(int INV, char* OS, int st)
    : invNummer(INV)
    , osName(OS)
    , state(st)
{};

int main()
{
    Computer* one;
    one = new Computer(10, (char*)"Windows", 1);
    delete one;
    Computer two(9, (char*)"Linux", 0);

    one->info();
    two.info();

    return 0;
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
0 Windows 1
9 Linux 0
```

Comment: Please don't do `(char *)"Windows"`.  Either use a `const char*` or use `std::string`/`std::string_view`

Comment: Please make sure your code survives language translation, C++ doesn't know that `eins` is `one`. Your main problem is that you delete the object `one` is pointing to which leaves the pointer dangling, dereferencing a dangling pointer invokes ub. Also you shouldn't cast a string literal, they're `const` because they live in read only memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought that wouldnt make a difference, but okay. But the problem with the dynamic variable still exists.

Comment: @It'scominghome Yeah sorry forgot about that, but my code in the editor is all in my language, so thats not the issue.

Comment: @Logiaa: No, it's exactly your issue. Unfortunately, you translated the code incorrectly here, making it hard to see. But you're deleting your pointer before you reference it, causing undefined behavior. Don't delete until you're done using it!

Comment: @FredLarson Okay my bad, youre right. Is it in general neseccary so delete the pointer again after creating it? I just saw that its the syntax, but didnt understand what it does.

Comment: Please learn about dynamic allocation. You can't figure this stuff out by trial and error.

Comment: @Logiaa Remove the `char*`  cast.  What warning or error does the compiler give you?  If you get warnings, why are you ignoring them?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The task tells me that I have to do it with char*, but adding "const" in the front solves the issue. And yeah I got a warning but with (char *) it went away.

Comment: There is no static allocation going on in the code you posted.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah I should really do that lol

Comment: @NeilButterworth Isnt  `Computer two(9, (char*)"Linux", 0);` static allocation?

Comment: Nope. It is automatic, stack-based allocation.

Comment: @Logiaa The warning went away because you told the compiler to shutup by applying the cast.  You did not "fix" anything.  Understand the warning the compiler is giving you instead of ignoring the warning, even worse, covering the warnings up by casting.

Comment: "Windows" is what's called a string literal. They are always constant arrays and could be stored in read only memory. Assigning it to a non-`const` pointer allows writing. Should you write to read only memory many bad things can happen.

Comment: @NeilButterworth With my example, what would static allocation look like?

Comment: For example: `static Computer two(9, (char*)"Linux", 0);`

Comment: Handy, if arcane, reading: [Storage Class Specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay I see, but the warning just said `deprecated conversion from string constant to char*`

Comment: That warning is considered to an error as of C++11. Odds are your compiler is being kind and allowing it to provide backwards compatibility with older code where it was merely frowned on but accepted because of decades of existing C code.

Answer (score 4):

As [@It's_comming_home pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432056/dynamic-variable-doesnt-work#comment89835088_51432056) to you, your issue is not related to creating the `one` object dynamically, but to the deletion of that object:

```
delete one;
```

When you delete the `one` object, the pointer is left dangling, ie it is no longer usable.  If you try to dereference it afterwards:

```
one->info();
```

You will get **undefined behavior**, like your output shows.

To fix this, just move the deletion of the `one` object after you invoke its `info()` method:

```
one->info();
two.info();

delete one;
```

Comment: I wanted to say that too, but yeah that fixed the problem, thanks